# how an associative array with the same name and different keys works on javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, key

I am a novice in javascript so forgive me if this question looks stupid. I have found this code as solution for managing items in a basket but I don't understand how this should work?!

```
function add(ref,nbr,price){
    if (basket[ref] == undefined) {
       basket[ref] = [];
       basket[ref]["nbr"] = nbr;
       basket[ref]["price"] = price;
    }else 
       basket[ref]["nbr"] += nbr;
}
```

Comment: What specifically about it are you asking about?

Comment: Have you tried stepping through this code in a debugger? That would probably clear up any confusion.

Comment: You can only have numeric indices inside an array - you want an object.

Comment: @JackBashford That's not true. Both objects and arrays can have string, numeric, and symbolic keys, though typically it's bad practice to use anything but numeric keys on arrays. An object seems to be more appropriate here (`basket[ref] = {}`), but not strictly necessary.

Comment: @p.s.w.g so javascript allows using non numeric keys (index) on arrays(not objects) ?

Comment: [Objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects) in JavaScript are basically a kind of hash table, and they support string, numeric, and (in recent editions) symbolic keys. [Arrays](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/First_steps/Arrays) in JavaScript are just a specialized kind of object (as MDN calls them "*list-like objects*") with some syntactic sugar and certain conventions (like generally only using numeric keys).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`basket` has some keys which can be used to look up values. When someone calls this function, they call it with a certain key to look up. Something may be there, or not. The code assumes that if something is there, it at least has the key `nbr`.

If something is at the key, `nbr` is added to that value (this is what happens in the `else` block). If not, a new value has to be initialized there.

The new value to store at this key is initialized in a nonstandard way: ordinarily you would use `{}` not `[]` since this is being used as an associative array not a sequential array. But in Javascript a sequential array is really just another kind of associative array and so this code is not incorrect.

Let's say basket contained: `{ refA: { nbr: 2, price: 3 } }` and someone called `add("refB", 2, 3)`. Here's what would happen:

1. Look up `refB` in `basket`. Basket has no such key, so the result is `undefined`. We enter the `if` block.
2. Set `refB` in `basket` to `[]`. Now `basket` looks like this: `{ refA: { nbr: 2, price: 3 }, refB: {} }` (Nevermind the distinction between `[]` and `{}` because it is misleading in this case.)
3. Set the key `nbr` on the new object to 3. This would not be possible without an object to set the key on, which is why step 2 is necessary. The result now looks like this: `{ refA: { nbr: 2, price: 3 }, refB: { nbr: 2 } }`
4. Finally, set `price` on the new object.

I hope this helps you understand how the code works. Finally, a more standard way to write this exact same code would be:

```
function add(ref,nbr,price){
    if (basket[ref] === undefined) {
       basket[ref] = { nbr: nbr, price: price }; // The shorthand for this in ES5 and later is { nbr, price }
    } else { 
       basket[ref].nbr += nbr;
    }
}
```